# Set pt to new name when pivot table name changes

Tags: excel, vba, pivot-table

I have a loop where I'm cycling through workbooks in a folder and pulling out specific values in the pivot table. The work books all have multiple sheets and pivot tables. I am running into an issue where the name of the pivot table changes and I'm having trouble with a workaround.

This is the current code sample that works up until **"PivotTable6"** changes to **"PivotTable1"**

```
Set pT = Sheets("sheet_name").PivotTables("PivotTable6")
wb_main.Worksheets("sheet_name").Cells(inc, 13).Value = pT.GetPivotData("field, item references etc").Value
```

Is there a way to update dynamically w/o hardcoding **"PivotTable1"** in. I will recycle this for other tables in the workbooks so I am trying to find a dynamic solution that pulls in the names of the pivot tables in the workbook and then based on the value I am looking for `Set pT = relevant table`.

Comment: Does the sheet have more than one pivot table?

Comment: Yes the sheet has several pivot tables

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Pivot Table name acts as an identifier for the Pivot table object. It would be really hard to find the pivot table you want without knowing its name. You would need to use another property (such as the `.Tag` proprety) that is harder for a user to change in order to stash an identifier of your own that only the code would know.

You can cycle through all the pivot tables in a workbook by using an iterative `for each` loop. In this way, you can systematically "visit" each pivot table in each sheet of each workbook.

```
Dim pt As PivotTable
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim ws As Worksheet

For Each wb In Application.Workbooks
    For Each ws In wb.Worksheets
        For Each pt In ws.PivotTables
            '// your code ...
            ws.Cells(inc, 13).Value = pt.GetPivotData("field, item references etc").Value
            '// some more of your code ...
        Next pt
    Next ws
Next wb
```

You can even check for conditions about the pivot tables as you visit them by throwing in some condition like `If pt.Name = "PivotTable1" Then ...` or `If pt.Tag = "CodeName" Then ...` if you're trying to do something specific to a specific pivot table.

Comment: I like the approach, was able to get exactly what I needed adding in some extra conditions within the for loops.